# Can I sum up feature vectors of a user‘s collection?

Tags: recommender-system, similarity, cosine-distance, vector-space-models

I want to find items that are similar to items users already have in their collection. Every item has attributes, so I created feature vectors where every element of the vector represents an attribute and is either $0$ or $1$ (if an item has that attribute).

For the user collection I summed up all vectors, creating one vector which I then used to calculate similarities with other items.

Is this a correct approach or should I make this "user vector", binary like the other ones? Or is it easier to just calculate $n \times m$ (I.e. user items and new items) similarities?

The set of new items will consist of $\sim1000$ items, while the user collections tend to be $<1000$. As similarity function I used cosine distance, but wanted to try Pearson coefficient as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use total sum of boolean values. That will be fast and give a general notion of similarity.

A more useful metric might be [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), the sum of matching booleans between two vectors.

Comment: Very late reply, but indeed! I will try that. Thank you.